# showevenifblank is not working as expected

Tags: codenameone

I need to show some labels even if label text is blank, but `setShowEvenIfBlank()` seems not working. If I add a blank space to the text labels they are shown, so it seems `setShowEvenIfBlank()` is not working. Can anyone tell me I can get this to work properly so I can show empty labels?

```
for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
{
    lb=new Label("");
    lb.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0x00ffffff); 
    lb.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0x60);
    lb.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(1)); 
    lb.setShowEvenIfBlank(true);
    cx.add(tx1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(33),lb);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, notice I made it red and opaque so it will stand out more:

```
Form hi = new Form("Label", BoxLayout.y());
Label lb =new Label(""); 
Style s = lb.getAllStyles();
s.setBgColor(0xff0000); 
s.setBgTransparency(255);
s.setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(1)); 
s.setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);
s.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
lb.setShowEvenIfBlank(true);

hi.add(lb);

hi.show();
```

I'm guessing you don't have enough padding to see the result... Also notice that you drew the line using theme colors which might be white.

[image]